# Restart ADB from Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adb

I previously developed on Eclipse and just migrated to Android Studio.
Everything works fine, it's better and faster.

I work on real device, and Android Studio recognizes it without issue.

But when I disconnect and reconnect my device, it doesn't recognize my device anymore, I have to exit and restart Android Studio.

I can't find a way to "Reset adb" like Eclipse Feature.

[image: Reset ADB from within Eclipse]

Can ADB be restarted from within Android Studio? If so, how?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

What I usually do when I get this error is restarting the `adb` server by typing in the command into `Terminal`:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

---

However this can be achieved in Android Studio. Clicking the `Monitor` button you can launch the same program you have referenced from Eclipse.

[image: Monitor]

---

[image: monitor 2]

If you do not see this you may need to update your `Platform Tools` from the SDK Manager button.

[image]

Comment: But no way to do from the main Android Studio window itself without using Android Device Monitor, right?

Comment: @wisbucky You can open a `Terminal` window via `View > Tool Windows > Terminal` in Android Studio then run `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`.

Comment: It's not even necessary to type `adb start-server` -- Android Studio will start it automatically when it's needed (e.g. to Run the program)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above working answer, the ADB can also be restarted during the restart of Android Studio ( File > Invalidate Cache / Restart > Just Restart ).

ADB is down for a reason, therefore a clean restart of Android Studio is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

that did trick for me thanks. resetting adb on android studio fixed my issue of ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'. spent 2 days trying look for solution to this