# Android studio emulator disconnected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

Please guide me i am beginner in android.
I don't know what going on i simply check the emulator in simple hello world program but emulator disconnected.
no error in program and also not show in log cat.

Comment: Please consider specifying your question. Maybe try to follow some tutorial on internet.

Comment: look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22667030/3326331)

Comment: emulator disconnected??Check for api level in emulator and in manifest file. I am sure It is out of range for emulator

Answer (score 0):

Please check **Tools>Connection Assistant**.
Or you can follow this manually;

1.Run your Hello World program and open your emulator.

2.Follow these on your emulator Android OS;

(1) On Android 8.0 and higher, go to **Settings > System > About phone**(or **About emulated device**) and tap Build number seven times.

(2) On Android 4.2 through 7.1.2, go to **Settings > About phone**(or **About emulated device**) and tap Build number seven times.

3.Return to the main Settings menu to find Developer options at the bottom. In the Developer options menu, scroll down and enable USB debugging.

Result;
[Usb Debugging Connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAYa2.png)

After did these, you can run your project;
[Hello World](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edBlY.png)