# Android Emulator Not connected on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

On first run the emulator after starting the Android studio, the emulator starts but Android Studio says **No Device Connected**. I need to start the emulator till it starts completely and only after that when i start the emulator the next time it gets connected. How can i fix the issue?
[image: Android Emulator started but not connected to Android Studio]

I am currently running **Android Studio AI-141.2024585**

Comment: reset you `adb`. why don't update your android studio 1.3 which is stable now?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667030/restart-adb-from-android-studio

Comment: @Rustam restarting the adb solved the problem for that instance but after restarting the windows it is still having the same problem. Android Studio AI-141.2024585 is the 1.3 beta version will try the stable version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click terminal option at the bottom,

Run command one : **adb kill-server**

Run command two : **adb start-server**

See this:

[image]

Comment: It worked After i upgrade my Android studio to Latest Stable version.

Answer (score -2):

For me it happened because somehow adb file from android/sdk/platform-tools missing I resolved it by adding missing adb.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038199/android-studio-platform-tools-missing-adb-exe/50340990) how you can add missing adb