# My device gets disconnected when i run the application

Tags: android

Device gets disconnected when i run the application.
Console shows the following message:

```
[2015-09-10 04:13:05 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
 java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:677)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:523)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:847)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:815)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:775)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:664)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:46)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:592)
```

Comment: Check again after reseting adb.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: using Windows 10 @CodePhobia

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22815606/4874271 Try this @mehran

Comment: @CodePhobia i have tried this alot , did not worked

Comment: I am inclined to feel this could be a Windows 10 related error the more comments I see. Tried it with a different device?

Answer (score 0):

Please try killing and restarting adb server by

```
adb kill-server
```

and then restart it with

```
 adb start-server
```

Sometimes, restarting Eclipse (assuming you are using it), resolves this problem as a secondary instance may have been launched before and is kept running.

Comment: what are you using to develop this app ?

Comment: Restaring it and killing the server process dont resolve anything ?

Comment: nothing at all. i tried it many times but it did not helped. i run the commands adb kill-server and adb start-server in cmd. it did not helped.